# Update ttl for all records in aerospike

Tags: configuration, lua, aerospike, ttl

I was stuck in a situation that I have initialised a namesapce with 
default-ttl to 30 days. There was about 5 million data with that (30-day calculated) ttl-value. Actually, my requirement is that ttl should be zero(0), but It(ttl-30d) was kept with unaware or un-recognise.

So, Now I want to update prev(old) 5 million data with new ttl-value (Zero).

I've checked/tried "set-disable-eviction true", but it is not working, it is removing data according to (old)ttl-value.

How do I overcome out this? (and I want to retrieve the removed data, How can I?).

Someone help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, [eviction](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/eviction-mechanisms-in-aerospike-3-8-and-onwards/2854) and expiration are two different mechanisms. You can disable evictions in various ways, such as the [`set-disable-eviction`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#set-disable-eviction) config parameter you've used. You cannot disable the cleanup of expired records. There's a good knowledge base [FAQ What are Expiration, Eviction and Stop-Writes?](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/faq-what-are-expiration-eviction-and-stop-writes/2311). Unfortunately, the expired records that have been cleaned up are gone if their *void time* is in the past. If those records were merely evicted (i.e. removed before their void time due to crossing the namespace [high-water mark](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#high-water-memory-pct) for memory or disk) you can cold restart your node, and those records with a future TTL will come back. They won't return if either they were [durably deleted](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/durable_deletes.html) or if their TTL is in the past (such records gets skipped).

As for resetting TTLs, the easiest way would be to do this through a [record UDF](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_record_udfs.html) that is applied to all the records in your namespace using a scan.

The UDF for your situation would be very simple:

**ttl.lua**

```
function to_zero_ttl(rec)
  local rec_ttl = record.ttl(rec)
  if rec_ttl > 0 then
    record.set_ttl(rec, -1)
    aerospike:update(rec)
  end
end
```

In [AQL](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql):

```
$ aql
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.12.0
C Client Version 4.1.4
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> register module './ttl.lua'
OK, 1 module added.

aql> execute ttl.to_zero_ttl() on test.foo
```

Comment: The lua function is not working properly, it creating scan job but not reflecting anything.I've checked in log too. How can I run?

Comment: (scan): (scan.c:1324) starting udf-bg scan job 15277761756515657433 {<ns>:<set>} priority 2; but nothing is changing and still data is deleting as usual (from logs).Is it updating records based on LastInFirstOut? If so how can I change to FIFO?

Comment: `execute` applies the UDF to each record pulled up by the scan. It does not return any value, it's running asynchronously. What you can look at is the TTL histogram before and after. Use [`asinfo`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/asinfo) to run those. `asinfo -v "hist-dump:ns=<namespace>;hist=ttl"` . You can also see in the [server logs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/serverlogmessages) how many `0-vt` records you have. That should be increasing until it covers all the records.

Comment: I'm continuosly getting this error(log file):: INFO (udf): (udf.c:1226) lua error, ret:0, what might be the reason?

Comment: You were right. (1) The update won't happen if the record isn't 'dirty'. I'm really doing nothing operationally other than assigning the first bin back to itself. This won't do anything at the server, but the UDF module will decide to actually do the update, applying the new TTL. (2) I needed to use TTL -1 which on the client side means 'never expire'. TTL 0 in the client means 'inherit the default TTL for the namespace'.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Python script would be easier if you have more complex logic, with filters etc.

```
zero_ttl_operation = [operations.touch(-1)]
query = client.query(namespace, set_name)
query.add_ops(zero_ttl_operation)
policy = {}
job = query.execute_background(policy)
print(f'executing job {job}')
while True:
    response = client.job_info(job, aerospike.JOB_SCAN, policy={'timeout': 60000})
    print(f'job status: {response}')
    if response['status'] != aerospike.JOB_STATUS_INPROGRESS:
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Aerospike v6 and Python SDK v7.