# Changing TTL for a set in Aerospike with AQL

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

I was just wondering, is there a way to change the TTL of a set through AQL query alone. I have gone through this aerospike page : https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/how-to-modify-ttl-using-udf/5608 and it says I will have to create a lua script and execute using aql query, which is fine.

Is there no support in AQL to change the TTL for a particular set using query alone i.e. without having to write a script?
Just curious.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, but changing the TTL with lua is easy, and everything is written here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/44988253/7252805

Answer (score 3):

I don't think with AQL you can do that without a lua module. However the lua module is quite simple. AQL does not have the ability to utilize Operations in execute(), which is the other way you could do using, say, a Java client.

(sets ttl to argument value, in seconds)

```
mymodule.lua  
============
function mytouch(rec, ttl_val)
   record.set_ttl(rec, ttl_val)
   aerospike:update(rec)
end
```

Now load this file to the server via AQL.

```
aql> register module "mymodule.lua"
OK, 1 module added.
```

I have 10 records, one of them is:

```
aql> set record_print_metadata true

aql> select * from test.testset where pk="key1"
select * from test.testset where pk="key1"
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
| name   | age | {ttl}  | {gen} |
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
| "Jack" | 26  | 431998 | 1     |
+--------+-----+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.002 secs)

OK
```

Lets set all records ttl to 100 seconds..

```
aql> execute mymodule.mytouch(100) on test.testset
execute mymodule.mytouch(100) on test.testset
OK, Scan job (13085139689609506765) created.

aql> select * from test.testset where pk="key1"
select * from test.testset where pk="key1"
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
| name   | age | {ttl} | {gen} |
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
| "Jack" | 26  | 98    | 2     |
+--------+-----+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)

OK
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i can see that this script will change the records of already written records. is there a way this script can be modified so that the records that are going to get inserted in future for this set get set with the ttl i want? i am curious if this is possible with UDFs.

Comment: when you insert a new record, in aql all you have to do is: aql> set record_ttl 100 and the aql> insert into ....  the record will be inserted with 100 sec ttl.

Comment: Underneath AQL, at C client level, which is what AQL uses, these are two different things, transactions wise. Record insertion is a write transaction where you set ttl through write policy. Modifying all records ttl is a scan operation which can only modify every record it finds via the lua module that you pass to the scan operation.

Comment: Note - using this technique, you can modify the ttl of an existing record. It is safe to use it to increase the ttl. If you use it to decrease the ttl, say a record had 3 months left and you reduce to 10 sec, it will expire in 10 sec but if the node was coldstarted, the 3 months version could potentially get resurrected. If using this to force expire records early, you may want to dd (wipe) the disk if restarting the node and fill back the data via migrations. Not the best thing to do unless you don't mind some records getting resurrected.